# What are properties of equal angle Pentagon??

Tags: geometry

So i have an equal angle pentagon sides are not equal i want to know what i can get to help solve a problem (wont state the problem since i want to solve it ).

I think that the angle bisector of a angle is perpendicular to the side that in front of it

Comment: What do you mean by "the angle bisector of an angle is perpendicular"? Perpendicular to what?

Comment: To the side that in front of it

Comment: @Brian This reminds me of a joke: On a topology final exam in one of the tasks two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ are described. The question is: are $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic? An answer of a student says: $X$ is homeomorphic, $Y$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

There's enough variability in the side-lengths of an equiangular pentagon that relations among them are tricky. (If you know three sides, you can solve for the remaining two, but that may not be helpful.)

[image]

However, you can certainly show (say, via an angle-sum argument) that an angle bisector of one angle is perpendicular to (the line containing) the opposite side. Note also that the sides are necessarily parallel to those of some regular pentagon; that parallelism may lead to other useful properties.

Comment: You can limit 2 of the other sides, using SAS from trig ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: I don't mean to suggest that sides are *completely* arbitrary; there *is* some structure here. It's true that if you fix, say, the top two edges of the "outside" pentagon in my figure, there are limits to how large the other sides can be; however, since you can "move" the bottom edge (keeping it parallel) within certain limits, changing all three non-fixed edges in concert, articulating exact relations takes some finesse. ... In any case, knowing more about the kind of question OP ultimately seeks to answer would help guide the search for "relevant" properties.